# Azure release pipeline error: Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings. Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable (CODE: 503)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have a Azure DevOps release pipeline which deploy a container to app service in Azure. When I run it, the task to deploy the container fails with message

2020-10-23T16:12:20.8516547Z ##[error]**Error: Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings. Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable (CODE: 503)**
2020-10-23T16:12:46.5212090Z ##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable (CODE: 503)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Did it happen once or more times?

Comment: it always happen :)

Comment: are you able to browse your kudu site?

Comment: The Kudu site shows 503 - service unavailable

Comment: This problem is often caused by application level issues, such as:1.requests taking a long time 2.application using high memory/CPU 3.application crashing due to an exception. Please refer to the troubleshooting steps [in this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503).

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT 谢谢Kevin, 明天我试试

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT.. when I try to open the Dudu site for my app, it just shows a blank page with error 

Service Unavailable

Does the Kudu site only run when the app is running?

Comment: @sean717 No, you should be able to get to the Kudu site even if the Web App is in a Stopped state. Please run through the Troubleshooting steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503).

Comment: This is solved. See the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542051/why-the-kudu-site-for-my-app-service-is-showing-503-service-unavailable

Comment: @sean717 Would you please post your answer and mark it? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers. Thank you.

Comment: We have the same issue while running this on CI, the only thing that makes it go through it to stop the app completely, run CI and then restart the app.