# Why the Kudu site for my app service is showing 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am having trouble deploying container to my app service in Azure. In the release pipeline, I saw the following error

[debug][PUT]https://$iagadsca01-cac-app-salesforcedownstream-01:***@iagadsca01-cac-app-salesforcedownstream-01.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/16801603731950666
[debug]Could not parse response: {}
[debug]Response: undefined
[debug]Encountered a retriable status code: 503. Message: 'Service Temporarily Unavailable'.

The pipeline will repeat the the above PUT operation for 20 mins and times out eventually.

When I try to open the Kudu site (*.scm) site for my web app, it just gave me a blank page with error

Service Unavailable

I think the scm site should be up regardless my app is running or not? What could cause the scm site to give Service Unavailable error?

Comment: The Kudu site should definitely be up, even in a failed deployment. If you go to your Web App management blade in the Azure Portal and navigate to "Process Explorer", do you see the scm site is running? You could perhaps kill the scm process there and it should reboot.

Comment: Hey @RobReagan.. thanks for the tip... but the Process Explorer is grey out and when I hover over, it says "this feature is not available for Linux apps"

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately I have zero experience with Linux WebApps, so I likely cannot be of much help. If you recycle the entire WebApp, do you have any luck? If not, my only other suggestion is to FTP into the instance and delete or reset files.

Comment: @RobReagan.. I restarted the app service a few times already and even deleted / recreated it.. but still no luck... anyways, thanks for the help and next I am going to try to get msft support involved.

Comment: I think you have reached that point. Best of luck. If you don't mind, can you post a resolution after you get things worked out with MSFT? I'm really curious as to how this is resolved.

Comment: I am very keen to get to the bottom of this and will post the answer here for sure

Comment: Given that you posted the same self answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64503765/azure-release-pipeline-error-failed-to-fetch-kudu-app-settings-error-service - are these questions in fact duplicates?

Comment: Yes, they essentially are. Should I delete this one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TL;DR: **scale up the app service plan and scale back.**

This is now solved after I had a support call with MSFT on Teams (my employer has a very high level SLA with MSFT, I was contacted in two hrs after submitting a request), see my summary here:

The support engineer found errors related to vNet for the app service and suggested to disconnect the app service from the vNet. We did that and the issue was solved – the scm site is no longer throw 503 error.

We enabled vNet connection again, and scm site started to give 503 error again. We thought we know the cause is vNet.

Then we kept the vNet connected, and scaled up the app service plan and scaled back – this will cause the app service migrate to another VM instance. After that – the scm remained working!

So we didn’t know if it is vNet which caused problem. The underlying VM probably messed up.

Comment: I have the same issue. The app does not get deployed to a vnet integrated function-app and the kudu link gives "service unavavailable". Tried recreating everything, still does not work. Microsoft just produces a lot of features, thus complicating everything, but with many bugs and rabbit-holes with this works with that but if you use this then that will not work and if that and this is used then something else does not work. This is how they spoiled windows-OS.

Comment: I only did the last part and it worked... so upscale, downscale to an even lower plan and done...

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Was hard to figure out what's going on due to 503 on kudu. In my recent case the issue was also with vnet, but **any scaling couldn't solve the problem**. When I disconnected app service from vnet, kudu started working, but I wanted it to be inside vnet. **It happened that I had vnet in one location and app service in the other.** Everything was setup through terraform. This configuration will not trigger any alerts, but apparently it is not possible to have it setup this way. **Problem was resolved when I put everything in one location.** Probably it would be also possible to have two vnets, one for each location, and peer them together (haven't tested this but seems to be a good solution also).

So remember, 503 on kudu will most likely has something to do with how the network is set up.

PS: I had to use different location for app service because I kept getting an error when trying to provision app plan in west europe stating that there's no capacity for another vm in that region and that's why I created app plan in north europe. And that's how I landed here.

Comment: This seems to match my situation.  I needed to replicate regions, but reusing the vnet setting for the original region was preventing my azure pipeline from completing the deploy to our staging slot for the new region.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility where I've seen this occur is in a faulty ARM deployment where the Azure App Service Plan for Linux did not have the `reserved` property set to true, and the Operating System defaulted to Windows despite the linux plan. Any app service deployed to that plan, configured correctly or otherwise, would appear to be ready to accept a code deployment, but would not successfully start, silently.

RobReagan's comment is right, this should not occur in a properly created resource, even with failed code deployments.

Answer (score 0):

My apps service plan was running approx 10 apps and was at 93% memory.
I shut down one of the apps, it dropped somewhere in 80% memory, and I could access the SCM sites again.

Its worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

One surprising cause for the App Service and Kudu site becoming unreachable appears to be misconfiguration. In my case the **Logging__LogLevel__Default** was improperly configured as "Info" whereas it should be "Information". Once configuration changed, we were able to discover an *extra log file* from the *now reachable /api/logs/docker/zip* on the SCM site. This log confirmed that KuduLite *itself* was utilizing Logging__LogLevel__Default as *configured for the aspnetcore application*. But the invalid Log Level brought down KuduLite.

That seems like a surprisingly fragile situation, but a mistake as simple as that can put the actual app-service out of commission, including its own diagnostics tool. I have no idea why the configuration of the aspnetcore app and the Kudu diagnostic tool would be so coupled. I thought these things were working completely on different levels and did not think it would feed off any of same the app-config variables, let alone that it would just *die* in such a manner with no hope of diagnosis. Indeed even App Monitor log queries cannot be served while it's in this "black hole" state.

We only discovered the issue after attempting to swap between a working Staging slot and Production. At that point *both slots* went into the "black hole" (the swap itself it wasn't clear if it completed or not, according to Azure). Eventually the Staging slot's SCM became reachable again when its Log Level went back to its own slot setting ("Trace" instead of "Info"), and its SCM logs (..._scm_docker.log) showed the unsupported log-level exception which prevented the swap from finishing. In theory we would've expected that during the Swap it would unearth the KuduLite error that was at the root of the problem. It's almost like the whole process depends on KuduLite telling us what's going on.