# Azure function deployment failed with status 503

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-deployment

I have a `yaml` pipeline which deploys a number of Azure Functions. The pipeline, which was working previously, has not been edited recently. The problem below started happening yesterday (27th Oct 2021).

When I run the pipeline, all the Azure Function deployments consistently fail with the same error on the first attempt. I retry the deployment and they all succeed on the second attempt.

Here's my error message:

[image]

In the Azure Resource Group Deployments tab, there is no sign of any failed deployments. I am deploying the the North Europe region. There are green lights across the board for [Azure service status](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status) and for [Azure devops status](https://status.dev.azure.com/).

I deploy my functions using the following yaml template.

```
parameters:
  environment: ''
  azureSubscription: ''
  appName: ''
  package: ''

jobs:
  - deployment: ${{parameters.package}}
    displayName: Deploy - Function - ${{parameters.package}}
    pool:
      name: 'Azure Pipelines'
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    dependsOn: ['ResourceDeployment']
    environment: ${{parameters.environment}}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: Steps.GetAzureResourceNames.yml

          - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription}}
              Action: 'Stop Azure App Service'
              WebAppName: $(GetAzureResourceNames.${{parameters.appName}})

          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription}}
              appType: 'functionApp'
              WebAppName: $(GetAzureResourceNames.${{parameters.appName}})
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.package}}/${{parameters.package}}.zip'
              enableCustomDeployment: true
              DeploymentType: 'runFromZip'

          - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription}}
              Action: 'Start Azure App Service'
              WebAppName: $(GetAzureResourceNames.${{parameters.appName}})
```

Anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: You can refer to [Use the Kudu Debug Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503#use-the-kudu-debug-console), [Why the Kudu site for my app service is showing 503 Service Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542051/why-the-kudu-site-for-my-app-service-is-showing-503-service-unavailable) and [Started getting deployment failures with 503](https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/gl6q9x/started_getting_deployment_failures_with_503/)

Comment: You can also open an issue on [azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues)

Comment: I've found that if you do a bad deployment to a resource, sometimes there is no way to recover - even after restarts. It could be worthwhile using your pipeline to deploy to fresh resource, if that works then you know it's the resource that is borked, not your pipeline - delete the borked resource and start over.

Comment: I deleted the azure resources and deployed them again. So far, it seems to have worked. It's not an ideal solution but c'est la vie.  @MattStannett, if you write that comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done @Connell.O'Donnell, I'm glad you got it resolved. I agree that it's not ideal but sometimes it's just easier to start over. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that if you do a bad deployment to a resource (publishing the wrong files or into the wrong directory), sometimes there is no way to recover - even after restarting it.

It could be worthwhile using your pipeline to deploy to fresh resource, if that works then you know it's the resource that is borked, not your pipeline.

The resolution would then be to delete and recreate the problematic resource, then revert your earlier changes to the pipeline so that you are deploying to the desired resource again.